# Mass Script Modification

Tags: bash

I have inherited a project that contains over 100x shell scripts spread over a fairly large file system.  I am looking for a clean way of finding all `.sh` files with in a directory and its children and replaces `#!/bin/bash.*` with:

```
#!/bin/bash +x
echo "[$(date +%H:%M:%S)] PWD:$PWD  -- $(dirname "$0")/$(basename "$(test -L "$0" && readlink "$0" || echo "$0")")" >> /script-log
```

I am currently using sublime to accomplish the task for content in version control ... however this does not help me with projects that have already been deployed.

I am thinking a combination of `find` + `grep` + `awk` would do this but I am not quite sure how to accomplish it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use find + sed to accomplish what you want. For example following command will replace shebang and add newline. Just add echo command to do the rest.

```
find ./  -name '*.sh' -exec sed -i 's/\#\!\/bin\/bash.*/\#\!\/bin\/bash\ \+x\'$'\necho \"\[\$\(date \+\%H\:\%M\:\%S\)\] PWD:\$PWD  -- \$(dirname "$0")\/\$(basename \"\$(test -L \"\$0\" \&\& readlink \"\$0\" || echo \"\$0\"\)\"\)\" \>\> \/scriptlog/' {} \;
```